# Is there a way to disable the command+up/command+down key combinations?

Tags: keyboard

Command+Left and Command+Right are both incredibly useful key combinations. By contrast, Command+Up and Command+Down are incredibly irritating. I almost never actually need a shortcut to the top of the document. 99 times out of 100, when I press Command+Up or Command+Down, it's by accident, usually when meaning to press one of the useful combinations. Is there any way to switch those two off?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**KeyRemap4MacBook**](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) with a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Disable ⌘↑ and ⌘↓</name>
    <identifier>DisableCMDUPandCMDDOWN</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE,
      KeyCode::VK_NONE
    </autogen>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE,
      KeyCode::VK_NONE
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Just `CURSOR_UP, VK_COMMAND` without `| ModifierFlag::NONE` would also disable for example option-command-up.